# Why is this allowed when using constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm having the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr int foo(int n){
    return n;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int p[foo(n)];
    cout << sizeof(p); // n * 4
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how is this possible to work OK? My compiler (C++ Builder XE6 - Clang) gives good result regarding sizeof but yet I passed non-constant 'n' to foo and it returned it as constant expression?

Comment: This is not because `foo` is `constexpr`; it would also be valid to pass `n` directly, because your compiler is allowing variable-sized arrays (http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_3.html#SEC49). I can't remember if that's an official feature of C++11 or not.

Comment: @Dave No, variable-length arrays are not allowed in C++11, it's coming in a limited form (compared to C) in C++14.

Comment: I just tried int p[n] and works OK! Now, I'm even more confused...

Comment: @Tracer Did you not just read Dave's comment?

Comment: @Tracer your compiler is allowing an extra feature (which according to Joachim Pileborg is non-standard, but will be soon). In short: you are taking advantage of special features of your compiler. It is not portable. Don't do it :P

Comment: Yes. I read at. That is why I'm confused since I don't know why is this allowed. Thanks @Dave

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, arrays of runtime bound are **not** in C++14. They got removed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely they are still coming soon-ish in a Technical Specification, right?

Comment: @TemplateRex, not soonish, no, the arrays TS isn't really making any progress currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compiler extension which allows non-compile-time-sized arrays. You don't need `foo` as it yields a compile-time value when possible, but of course it also works at runtime when you pass a non-compile-time argument.

The funny thing is that now even `sizeof(p)` is ***not*** a compile-time value anymore:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr int foo(int n){
    return n;
}

template<unsigned n> void f();

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int p[foo(n)];
    f<sizeof(p)>(); // oops
    return 0;
}
```

yields:

```
main.cpp:14:18: error: '(long unsigned int)((((sizetype)<anonymous>) + 1u) * 4u)' is not a constant expression

     f<sizeof(p)>(); // oops
                  ^
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce7e2142ec2a1af8)